# How to call a view from a view model using MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have two view models A and B. On a double click on view A I need to display view B.
How can I call a view B from a view Model A using the `MVVM` pattern?

I have looked around and I couldn't find a clear example that demonstrate this fundamental concept for the `MVVM` pattern.

## c#

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm;
using System.Windows.Input;


namespace Example.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModelA : BindableBase
    {
        
      public ICommand ShowInfoCommand { get; private set; }
            
      //Need to call view B  
      private void OnShowInfo(object obj)
        {
             //To Be Implemented
        }
      
    }
}
```

Comment: have you searched for navigation? https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/

Comment: @Mat No,I didn't come across this link. Please post it as an answer. Thank you :)

Comment: Off-site links do not constitute valid answers on stackoverflow. An answer has to be self-contained.

Comment: You should think of the ViewModel as the current state of your application.  Its surface features contain access points from the outside world (ICommand properties).  The View pipes user input into the view model via these access ports.  The ViewModel's surface also contains expressions of the current state of the application (all other properties). The View observes the ViewModel for state changes and reacts as appropriate.  This often takes the form of updating the UI, but it can also take the form *of displaying different views.*  This can be accomplished in many different ways...

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's an easy way to do this (assuming you have correctly implemented INotifyPropertyChanged):

Go to your App.xaml and declare some DataTemplates to connect the Views with the ViewModels:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ViewModelA}">
    <Views:ViewA />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ViewModelB}">
    <Views:ViewB />
</DataTemplate>
```

Now whenever your application uses ViewModelA or ViewModelB, these DataTemplates will set the correct views. 
You can have a content presenter or content control to control which view model to display:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel}" />
```

Then, you will set the ViewModel, whenever you wish to change views:

```
//Need to call view B  
private void OnShowInfo(object obj)
{
    ViewModel = new ViewModelB();
}
```

Well, that's it. Your ViewModel binding of the ContentControl together with the DataTemplates will do the job! 
Of course, there are plenty of different approaches to do this. It will depend on your requirements. I'm currently using NavigationService to handle this in one of my projects.